# SSRS Expressions For end of week date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I need to use an SSRS expression to find two dates -

> 1. The date that's the end of this week.
> 2. The dates that's the start of the week, 2 weeks ago.

For example, if today is `27/05/2016`

> 1 = 29/05/2016
>
> 2 = 09/05/2016

This needs to be dynamic e.g. getdate()

I'm using these functions to filter a matrix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be something like below,

***1. The date that's the end of this week.***

```
=DateAdd("d", 7 - DatePart("w", CDate(Today)), CDate(Today).AddDays(1)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

***2. The dates that's the start of the week, 2 weeks ago.***

```
=DateAdd("d", 2 - WeekDay(Today), DateAdd("d", -14, Today).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

***[SSRS Expression Cheat Sheet](http://pragmaticworks.com/Training/Resources/Cheat-Sheets/SSRS-Expression-Cheat-Sheet)***

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this, 
***End of this week***

```
 =DateAdd("d", 8 - Weekday(Today), Today).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

***Start of the week (2 weeks ago)***

```
 =DateAdd("d", -(Weekday(Today)+12) , Today).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```